# Can I use household vacuum cleaner with AquaFilter as construction/industrial one

Tags: grinding

I'm going to buy Thomas vacuum cleaner with Aqua filter and use it to sand walls a bit with grinder. And after finishing the decoration, use it as an ordinary cleaner. May construction plaster, putty sanding harm it? Or it is OK to use the household vacuum for small amount of grinding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I've bought household Thomas Multi Clean X10 Parquet vacuum with Aqua filter and rent the industrial cleaner Hilti VC-40UM with Hilti DGH-130 concrete grinder. There was about 2 full buckets of dust, I cleaned the filter for Hilti about 10 times during work of single small 3x5 meters room. So I can say that household cleaner won't last after such an action. In addition to that Aqua filter passes about 20% of dry dust through. Then it is being caught by sponges and microfiber filter before the engine. I suppose 20% dust from 2 buckets would be enough to kill those filters

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it will last.

Professional units are designed for higher duty hours with more suction etc which means better bearings and greater power for example.

The home use equipment is not designed to be used at that type of duty hours - possibility of overheating etc.

A simple example is a toaster - buy one for a home and it is designed to do 4 or 8 slices per morning per day. Put that same toaster in a canteen feeding 200 workers per morning for breakfast and it might last 2 days... home use it can last 5 years.